# Construction of hash function with a given distribution

Tags: probability-theory, hash, hash-tables, probabilistic-algorithms, hashing

Two questions about the construction of a hash function:
Let $U = \{u_1,...,u_n\}$ be a set of size $n$, and suppose that one is interested in a function $h\colon U \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $h$ "looks like" it maps each of the $u_i$s  to a random number, chosen from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. One simple way to construct such $h$ is to store in the memory a table of size $n$, and saving, for each element $ u_i$, the corresponding random sample. This is obviously very inefficient, and impossible to do if $U$ is infinite (or even continuous). Are there known approaches (or lower bounds) for the discrete, finite case? Are there approaches for the continuous case (i.e. $U$ is a continuous set)?
Clarification for the continues domain case:
Suppose that $U = \mathbb{R}$. What I am after is a function $h : U \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $h(u)$ has the property of "being random" i.e. if you sample many points from $\mathbb{R}$, and look at $h(x_1),...,h(x_m)$ they would look like numbers which were sampled from uniform distribution

Comment: Use a hash function. Interpret the result as the binary expansion of a number in $[0,1)$.

Comment: Are there hash functions for continuous domains?

Comment: In your case it’s the *range* which is continuous.

Comment: I am also interested in a continuous domain: $h : U \rightarrow [0,1]$ where $U$ is a continuous set

Comment: This sounds like a different question... the model isn’t completely clear, anyhow. How is the input accessed? What are the required properties?

Comment: Suppose that $U = \mathbb{R}$. What I am after is a function $h : U \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $h(u)$ has the property of "being random" i.e. if you sample many points from $\mathbb{R}$, and look at $h(x_1),...,h(x_m)$ they would look like numbers which were sampled from uniform distribution

Comment: You should either update this question or ask this as a separate one.

Comment: edited the original question, thanks

Comment: How do you apply a function on a real number? What is your computation model?